# XML::Compile maxOccurs="1" seems unbounded

Tags: xml, perl, xsd

I am having trouble understanding the output from the perl schema complier, it appears that in some cases the maxOccurs indicator is ignored.  If I try to use a complex element more than once, the first reference seems correct, however subsequent references are output as arrays even when the maxOccurs indicator is set to "1".  I only started playing with xml schemas, so my understanding is very limited.

I have to following schema (sorry, I tried to cut it down as much as possible):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Top">   
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>         
        <xs:element ref="Foo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="Bar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>         
        <xs:element ref="Bar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Bar">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="Baz" use="optional" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

When I run:

```
perl -MXML::Compile::Schema -e 'print XML::Compile::Schema->new("example.xsd")->template("PERL", "Top");'
```

I get the following output:

```
# is an unnamed complex
{ # sequence of Foo, Bar

  # is an unnamed complex
  # is optional
  Foo =>
  { # sequence of Bar

    # is an unnamed complex
    # is optional
    Bar =>
    { # is a xs:anyType
      # becomes an attribute
      Baz => "anything", }, },

  # is an unnamed complex
  # complex structure shown above
  # is optional
  Bar => [{},], }
```

"Bar" as an element of Foo appears as a complex (as expected), However "Bar" under the top level appears and list of complex, even though maxOccurs="1" (not what I am expecting).  Is my understanding just wrong or is my schema incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output will always be an array, but in your case it's limited to size one. This is to keep the syntax for accessing the data consistent regardless of the `maxOccurs` value.

Comment: Thanks AKHolland, I was trying to create a Class::Struct for each entity so that I could populate them a little easier, but in this case Bar is initialized as an array.  I think I might have to walk the entire dom tree to accomplish this and that might is probably not worth the trouble.